# Add centered text inside iframe, inside shortcode

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

I want to add centered text inside iframe, inside WordPress shortcode for videos that I removed from site and can be searched inside YouTube.

```
function my_title_search( ){
   $my_title = get_the_title();
echo '<div class="myIframe">
<iframe src="" width="100%">
<div class="removed_video">This video is removed from our site</div>
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query='.$my_title.'">Search YouTube for this video.</a>
</iframe>
</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'my_title_search', 'my_title_search' );
```

I am trying something like that, sorry if there is mistake in this code.
I have css for iframe to be responsive:

```
.myIframe {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 30px;
height: 0;
overflow: auto; 
-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch; 
border: solid black 1px;
} 
.myIframe iframe {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

Now, text should be centered inside iframe box, like this:
This video is removed from our site
Search YouTube for this video
One under another, Im not sure how to format it here.

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Use text:align:center; inside .myIframe iframe {}